# Google Analytics - Distinguishing between the free and paid version of my app

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I'm new to using Google Analytics in applications, and I want to have a clear way of distinguishing free users versus paid users of my app.

So far, I'm considering using three different properties to track this (one for overall, one for free only, and one for paid only), however, I get the feeling there may be a better way to do this.

I've been reading over GA categories, which seems interesting and applicable, but I'm not finding much information on them on the net.

Does anyone here have a recommendation for separating free/paid analytics in a clean and concise manner whilst preferably having a good overview of app usage in general?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a custom dimension on a user level (since presumably users won't usally flip between paid and unpaid versions).  That way you can set up filters to have different views for paid/unpaid and still have a rollup view that displays values from both versions (for example to see how users behave that eventually upgrade to the paid version).